# How to update the uploaded image style on S3 when image is replace by same filename?

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal-7

When replacing image with same file name is not updating the image style on S3. I tried to upload the image to S3 and the image gets uploaded successfully but the image style is not updated/changed for the uploaded image on S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use following code:

```
  $imgage_path_uri = 'Path of image URI';
$derivative_uri = image_style_path('my_image_style', $imgage_path_uri);
$style = image_style_load('my_image_style');
// Generate derivative
$generated = image_style_create_derivative($style, $imgage_path_uri, $derivative_uri);
$s3_bucket = variable_get('s3fs_bucket', '');
$derivative_uri_u = str_replace('s3://', 'public://', $derivative_uri);
$derivative_uri = str_replace('s3://', '', $derivative_uri);
try{
  $config = _s3fs_get_config();
  $s3 = _s3fs_get_amazons3_client($config);
}catch(S3fsException $e){
  form_set_error('form', $e->getMessage());
   return FALSE;
}
$result = $s3->deleteObject(array(
  'Bucket' => $s3_bucket,
  'Key'    => $derivative_uri
));
//create destination 
$destination = file_stream_wrapper_uri_normalize($filepath .'/'. $filename);
//move your image file to from source to destination
$destination = file_unmanaged_move($source, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$dafd = image_style_create_derivative($style, $destination, $derivative_uri_u);
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $s3_bucket,
    'Key'          => $derivative_uri,
    'SourceFile'   => $derivative_uri_u,
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
));
```

file_unmanaged_delete($derivative_uri_u);